# Gradient image showing a silver bar

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome

I have used an image with a gradient as a background image @: http://lotcapture.burnseo.com/

The image has a Photoshop gradient and was saved as a png.
As far as I can tell, this only occurs in Chrome on a Mac but it's bothering me severely because I cannot figure out why a gradient image would be displaying a silver bar where the gradient is:

CSS:

```
.wide-slider {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
background-image: url('/images/sky-home.png');
padding-left: 100%;
margin-left: -100%;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
padding-right: 100%;
margin-right: -100%;
top: -80px;
border-top: solid 5px #E9E9E9;
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What gradient?  You have no gradient.

Comment: The image was saved with a gradient in Photoshop. It was created in Photoshop with a gradient from black to transparent so the the sky image shows at the top and then fades at the bottom. The image is being displayed weird in Chrome on the Mac. Any reason why?

Comment: Is the image supposed to be 'tiled'?   If not, you could try changing repeat-x to no-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're referring to "Layer Masks" in Photoshop when you say:

> *The image was saved with a gradient in Photoshop. It was created in
>   Photoshop with a gradient from black to transparent so the the sky
>   image shows at the top and then fades at the bottom.*

I tried to display only background image (which link is **[this one](http://lotcapture.burnseo.com/images/sky-home.png)**) and I don't see a gradient that fades to transparent, so problem is in your image and not in Browser's rendering, also because in in Firefox and Chrome for Windows, it appears in the same way.